# "include" not working in php file cant reference the function

Tags: php, function, session, include, warnings

I am trying to put a function that I will commonly use in its own file. Then, I want to include that file so I have access to the function (or so I think).

activity.php (this is the function I want to be able to use)

```
<?php
function activity() {
$inactive = 600;

    // check to see if $_SESSION["timeout"] is set
    if (isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
        // calculate the session's "time to live"
        $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
        if ($sessionTTL > $inactive) {
            $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = false;
            session_destroy();
            echo "session destroyed";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "You need to log in.";
    }
}
?>
```

Here is showuser.php (the file where the error occurs):

```
<?php
    include ('activity.php');
    session_start();

    // check to see if $_SESSION["timeout"] is set
    activity();

    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $uname="root"; // Mysql username
    $password="xxx"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="itit"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="users"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select database.
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $password, $db_name);
    if($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["username"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($em);
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
    else {
        echo "You are not logged in.";
    }
?>

<h2>Username - Email</h2>
<div id="userinfo"><? echo $_SESSION["username"] ?> - <? echo $em ?></div>

<? 
    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

The function should check to see if the session has timed out, unless I am doing something wrong with that code...

I get these errors when running the scripts which include the file:

```
Warning: include(activity.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Eamon/Sites/templates/showuser.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/activity.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Users/Eamon/Sites/templates/showuser.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Users/Eamon/Sites/templates/showuser.php:2) in /Users/Eamon/Sites/templates/showuser.php on line 3

Fatal error: Call to undefined function activity() in /Users/Eamon/Sites/templates/showuser.php on line 6
```

**UPDATE**

I did this instead

```
include ('../activity.php');
```

This got rid of all the errors except for the "Warning: session_start" error.

Comment: so? is the activity.php file in the same directory as the script you're trying to include it from? No? then is it one of the other directories mentioned in the include_path in the error message?

Comment: @MarcB ...if u see my update i think i fixed some of the errors...but not the session_start warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: the session warning is caused by output being performed before the header() call that session_start() executes. the error tells you EXACTLY where the output is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with the directory where PHP is looking for the file.
Try changing it to `include ('./activity.php');`

Answer (score 0):

If activity.php is in `/Users/Eamon/Sites/templates/` you can change your include to

```
include (__DIR__'."/activity.php');
```

and it should work for you.

Comment: thanks...does what I did in my update do the same thing? and did u see that i have only one error left?

Comment: my method get the absolute path... yours get the path one directory up from the current working directory. in this case they refer to the same location but if the cwd changes then yours will give you errors again.

Comment: but of course if `../activity.php` worked in your case then my example should be `include (__DIR__."/../activity.php');`

Comment: The session_start error is the result of sending output prior to starting the session,it appears as though the culprit is at line 2 of /Users/Eamon/Sites/templates/showuser.php

Comment: @Orangepill...thanks - the activity() function uses a session variable...that is why i couldnt include the file until after session_start()...thanks for your help